# facebook ogpでog:imageを読んでいるのにサムネイルが表示されない

Tags: cakephp, facebook, facebook-graph-api

cakePHPで
https://github.com/monsat/Ogp
を使って設定をしています。

1: デバッガを見てみると`<meta property="og:image" content="http://[sample.com]/aaa/bbb.jpg" />`と問題なく読み込まれている

2: `title`や`appid`, `property`も問題ない

3: キャッシュをクリアして何度も再スクレイピング済み

4: 画像サイズも十分に大きい。

5: 以前は問題なかった。

ですが、シェアボタンでシェアしたり、リンクを貼り付けるとサムネイルが一切読み込まれないようになってしまいました。

どなたか似たようなエラーを過去にお持ちの方で解決方法をご存知の方、ご教授願います。

Answer (score 1):

> the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered
>   image
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching

のよう（最初にシェアする人には画像が見えない）です。

上記ページに記載されてり、下記いずれかの方法でいかがでしょうか？

1. [URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) を使ってキャッシュを生成させる
2. og:image:width と og:image:height を指定する